# Unable to read file due to Access denied issue in C#

Tags: c#, android

I am try to read a .txt file which is present in my Tablet in `/mnt/sdcard/` location via C#. Whenever I execute the program I see below **error msg**

> Access to the Path /mnt/sdcard/.android_secure is denied.

Added the permission in the code Activity as shown in below code, but still I am unable to access the file.

Went through n number of Threads but none of them are clear.

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;

namespace Server

{
         [Activity (Label = "Server", MainLauncher = true, Permission = "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE")]

    public class Activity1 : Activity
            {
        int count = 1;
        protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)

        {
            base.OnCreate (bundle);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource

            SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);
            Button button = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.myButton);

            button.Click += delegate {
            button.Text = string.Format ("{0} clicks!", count++);};

    string path = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath;
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(path,"*.txt",SearchOption.AllDirectories); //In this line I see Access denied error in run time.

        }
    }
}
```

If any one have come acrossed this issue and found solution please share it...

Thanks
Deepak

Comment: what framework do you use? why not using Java SDK?

Comment: Is your storage mounted? If so, you can't access it until it is unmounted.

Comment: Related: [Why root cannot access “.android_secure” directory on external SD card?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/221485/218526)

Answer (score 0):

With following lines of code I am to read .txt file present on my Android Tablet

string path = Path.Combine(Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.Path, "IVIFile.txt");

```
        using (FileStream fsSource  = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))

        {

            byte[] bytes = new byte[fsSource.Length];

            int numBytesToRead = (int)fsSource.Length;



            while (numBytesToRead > 0)

            {

                byte[] b = new byte[numBytesToRead];

                UTF8Encoding temp = new UTF8Encoding(true);

                while (fsSource.Read(b,0,b.Length) > 0)

                {

                    Console.WriteLine(temp.GetString(b));

                }

            }

        }
```